# Can't locate items in minor axis

Tags: python, panel

I am trying to do some `pd.Panel` manipulation with the following panel:

```
print(panell)
print(panell.shape)
```

gives:

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 9 (items) x 60 (major_axis) x 114 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 31.5hz to 8000hz
Major_axis axis: 2018-10-22 07:00:00 to 2018-10-24 18:00:00
Minor_axis axis: (1, 1) to (38, 3)

(9, 60, 114)
```

Then I want to loop over the `minor_axis` but it fails to locate the correct labels. Example, both:

```
print(panell.loc[:,:,'(38, 3)'])
print(panell[:,:,'(38, 3)'])
```

gives:

```
KeyError: 'the label [(38, 3)] is not in the [minor_axis]'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @jezrael I don't understand your question. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: Also you can check type of value by `print (type(wp.minor_axis[0]))`.

Comment: `print(panell[:,:,(38, 3)])` gives the same error: `KeyError: 'None of [(38, 3)] are in the [minor_axis]'`.

`print(type(panell.minor_axis[0]))` gives `<class 'tuple'>`

Comment: `print(panell.loc[:,:,[(38, 3)]])` works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need select by tuple in list:

```
print(panell.loc[:,:,[(38, 3)]])
```

because:

```
print (type(panell.minor_axis[0]))
<class 'tuple'>
```